# Installing package from source in Indigo

Tags: ros, source, package, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I know this question has been asked dozen of times already. So sorry for asking it again, but I really have problems dealing with it and I'm trying for hours now. It seems like the answers for older releases of ROS don't work for Indigo or maybe just for me. :(

I'd just want to install the [descartes-package](https://github.com/ros-industrial-consortium/descartes/tree/indigo-devel) from source as there is no `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-descartes`.

Can somebody help me out here please?

**Edit:**

Among others I already tried [this approach](http://answers.ros.org/question/60570/how-do-i-install-and-run-a-ros-package/):
there when I type `rosws set --svn https://github.com/ros-industrial-consortium/descartes.git`  the error appears `ERROR in config: Command requires a target workspace.`

also this [one](http://answers.ros.org/question/115261/how-to-install-an-individual-package-in-ros-hydro/):
but when entering `wstool merge descartes_catkin.rosinstall`, I get the error `ERROR in config: Is not a local file, nor a valid URL [descartes_catkin.rosinstall] : unknown url type: descartes_catkin.rosinstall`

In my distress I then tried `git clone https://github.com/ros-industrial-consortium/descartes.git -b -indigo-devel` and then `catkin_make` as this was the way to get the UR-package. But then in the C-API the `#include <descartes_moveit/moveit_state_adapter.h>` and the other includes of descartes coud not be recognized by the compiler.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208963/installing-package-from-source-in-indigo/) by [bluefish](https://answers.ros.org/users/21682/bluefish/) on ROS Answers with karma: 236 on 2015-05-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-05-11**:
Please add what you have already tried, why, and how it failed, so you won't get answers telling you things you already know.

**Comment by [bluefish](https://answers.ros.org/users/21682/bluefish/) on 2015-05-11**:
Thanks gvdhoorn for your help!! I edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You'll probably want to read up on catkin and workspaces in the [catkin tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials).

For your specific case:

```
# make sure you have sourced the correct setup.bash file for your ROS distribution already

# go to workspace src space
cd /path/to/your/catkin_ws/src

# checkout the desired version of the descartes repository.
git clone -b indigo-devel https://github.com/ros-industrial-consortium/descartes.git

# we need to make sure you have all dependencies installed.
cd /path/to/your/catkin_ws
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo

# now build
catkin_make
```

After sourcing `/path/to/your/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` you should now be able to use the Descartes packages.

---

Edit: just for completeness sake:

Your first approach uses `rosws`, which afaik has been deprecated in favour of `wstool` and probably doesn't work very well with anything more recent than Fuerte/Groovy. The second approach uses `wstool` and a `.rosinstall` file, which can work, but is probably overkill for a workspace with a single package. Your third attempt is basically correct, but you missed the step where you install all the dependencies of the package with something like `rosdep`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bluefish](https://answers.ros.org/users/21682/bluefish/) on 2015-05-11**:
Thanks a lot both for the answer and the explanations.
This plus editing CMakeLists.txt and package.xml which I also forgot in the first place did the trick. It works now. Thanks! :)

**Comment by [papaclaudia](https://answers.ros.org/users/25634/papaclaudia/) on 2016-03-06**:
Hi! I had a similar issue (on PC with ubuntu 14.04 with indigo-desktop-full version) and I solved my problem in the same way. Now on a board using ubuntu 14.04 with indigo-desktop version if I follow your steps I received this message after the "catkin_make" command:

**Comment by [papaclaudia](https://answers.ros.org/users/25634/papaclaudia/) on 2016-03-06**:
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "pcl_conversions"
with any of the following names:

```
pcl_conversionsConfig.cmake
pcl_conversions-config.cmake
```

**Comment by [papaclaudia](https://answers.ros.org/users/25634/papaclaudia/) on 2016-03-06**:
Add the installation prefix of "pcl_conversions" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
set "pcl_conversions_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.
If "pcl_conversions" provides a separate development package or SDK, be
sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):

**Comment by [papaclaudia](https://answers.ros.org/users/25634/papaclaudia/) on 2016-03-06**:
navigation/costmap_2d/CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed

**Comment by [papaclaudia](https://answers.ros.org/users/25634/papaclaudia/) on 2016-03-06**:
Sorry but I had to divide the message into three parts. How do I fix? Thank you!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-03-06**:
Please search for older questions about this (use google, with something like `site:answers.ros.org` added). If you can't find anything, please open a new question.